# Android 6. App crashes when pass byte array between activity

Tags: android

I need to return byte array from camera activity to main activity.

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
            dataIntent.putExtra("image", data);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataIntent);
            finish();
        }
    };
```

It's works perfect on android 4,5 . But on android 6 app crashes(without printing error log) . 
If i comment `"dataIntent.putExtra("image", data);"` line. App go back to main activity correctly.

Comment: Do you have selected in Android Studio (Android Monitor) `Show only selected applications`?  Maybe then you will see some errors, please select `No Filters`

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess is you need to implement [runtime permisssions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to get user permission to use the camera or read and write to an external storage... at runtime. This can be then saved by the user or revoked at any time, but will need to be managed in the manifest and when you call the use of the camera.

This has changed from android 6, where user permissions on install are no longer required, but instead runtime permissions are needed for certain actions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Android 6 phone has better camera than your Android 4 device? Do you know about Parcelable extra's size limit?

See Android docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html